# Netgear R6250 router not port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm attempting to forward port 9000 (custom SSH port) to one of my machines. I've set up a static local IP address and a port forwarding rule in the router settings, but I'm just getting "connection timed out" every time.

I can login to SSH on the local network so I know that's fine. I've rebooted the router and the machine multiple times, but to no avail. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Another thing that might be important is the way internet is provided to my apartment. I live in a complex where they have a huge bulk account with TWC, and they maintain all the modems (I guess) somewhere else in the building. There is an ethernet drop in my apartment where I have my router set up. I don't quite know enough about networking, but is it possible/likely that they have it set up in a way that would leave me unable to use port forwarding?

Comment: can you show output of `tracepath 8.8.8.8`? (remember to mask your public IP though) and try to test from an external box `nmap -p 9000 x.x.x.x` may help.

Comment: Is there another router between the R6250 and your provider ? Most likely the port in not forwarded on the next router/modem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is what I suspected: my router is actually behind another router (which is outside of my control).

I learned this from running a traceroute to google.com. Here is the output I got (with my public IP x'd out):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.216.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  5.234 ms  4.900 ms  4.603 ms
 2  10.32.254.2 (10.32.254.2)  4.295 ms  4.006 ms  3.720 ms
 3  rrcs-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.central.biz.rr.com (xx.xx.xxx.xxx)  3.432 ms  3.150 ms  2.863 ms
 4  be24.clmkohpe01r.midwest.rr.com (65.189.140.162)  15.875 ms  15.545 ms  15.263 ms
 5  bu-ether25.chctilwc00w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com (107.14.19.16)  23.651 ms  23.379 ms  23.101 ms
 6  bu-ether11.chcgildt87w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com (66.109.6.20)  27.078 ms  49.076 ms  48.716 ms
 7  216.3.52.41 (216.3.52.41)  48.317 ms  48.048 ms  47.777 ms
 8  216.3.52.54 (216.3.52.54)  94.608 ms  94.334 ms  94.061 ms
 9  216.239.42.136 (216.239.42.136)  115.270 ms  75.523 ms  75.069 ms
10  216.239.51.227 (216.239.51.227)  27.140 ms  26.871 ms  30.940 ms
11  ord31s22-in-f238.1e100.net (216.58.216.238)  35.000 ms  34.726 ms  24.944 ms
```

The 192.168.x.x address is the router in my apartment. Since the next hop is 10.x.x.x (another common private IP address range), I know it must be another router.

As a result, it seems I won't be able to do any kind of traditional port forwarding. For my purposes, I think the only remaining solution will be to use a reverse SSH tunnel from a VPS which I happen to have.